# Mips Assembly: Incorrect math calculations

Tags: assembly, mips

Here is my code:

```
    .data #Data section
Prompt1: .asciiz    "Enter number of terms(n): "
Prompt2: .asciiz    "Enter first term:  "
Prompt3: .asciiz "Enter nth term: "
Space: .asciiz "\n"
Result1: .asciiz "Common difference between terms is: "
Result2: .asciiz "Sum of first n terms is: "
RerunPrompt:     .asciiz "Do you want to calculate again?: "
EndStatement: .asciiz "\nThe program has ended.
                        \nCreated by: "

.globl main

.text #Code section

main:

li $t9, 1
li $t8, 2

startupMessage:
#Enter number of terms
li $v0, 4 #system call code for Print String
la $a0, Prompt1 #load address of Prompt1 into $a0
syscall #print the Prompt1 message

li $v0, 5 #system call code for Read Integer
syscall #reads the value of 1st integer into $v0
move $t0, $v0 #move the 1st integer to $t0

#Enter first term
li $v0, 4 #call to print string
la $a0, Prompt2 #load prompt2 into variable $a0
syscall #call system to print

li $v0, 5 #call to read integer
syscall #read integer into $v0
move $t1, $v0                        

#Enter nth term
li $v0, 4
la $a0, Prompt3
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t2, $v0

#Math functions
d:
#an-#a1
sub $t3, $t2, $t1
#n-1
sub $t4, $t0, $t5
# div 2
div $t3, $t4

mfhi $t5

Sn:
add $s0, $t2, $t1
div $s0, $t8

mflo $t6

Result:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, Result1
syscall

li $v0, 1
li $t5, 5
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, Space
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, Result2
syscall

li $v0, 1
li $t6, 5
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, Space
syscall

#Rerun Prompt1
li $v0, 4
la $a0, RerunPrompt
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t3, $v0

bne $t3, $zero, startupMessage
```

I ran a test with this code, and got some bizzare results. Also should note, both of the results are the same regardless of input.

**Console Output**

Enter first number of terms(n): 3

Enter first term: 2

Enter nth term: 15

Common difference between the terms is: 268501058

Sum of first n terms is: 268501095

Do you want to calulcate again?: 0

**Expected Output**

Enter first number of terms(n): 3

Enter first term: 2

Enter nth term: 15

Common difference between the terms is: 6.5

Sum of first n terms is: 25.5

Do you want to calulcate again?: 0

**The mathematical formula**
Common difference: (an - a1)/n-1
Sum of first n terms: ((an + a1)/2)*n

Not sure where I am going wrong, and why the result is consistent regardless of variable inputs.

Comment: `268501058` is an address, which is just a number so prints out like that.  If we look at that value in hex `10010042`, it is clearly an address in the .data section.

Comment: Single step in the debugger, and verify that each individual instruction does what you expect, and doesn't do what you don't expect.

Comment: System call 1 expects the value to print in register `$a0`. I'm also not quite sure how you're expecting floating-point results when you're only doing integer arithmetic and integer printing.

Comment: @Michael I have figured out the issue, I transitioned to floating point registers, thank you